# Probability of no return to zero until and including time $2n$ in a random walk

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider the random walk on the integer number line $\mathbb{Z}$ which starts at 0 and at each step $k$ moves $\epsilon_k=+1$ or $\epsilon_{k}=-1$
with equal probability $1/2$. The probability that a return to $0$ occurs at time $2n$ is denoted by $u_{2n}$ and the chance that a first return to origin occurs at $t=2n$ is denoted by $f_{2n}$.

Let $s_{2n}$ denote the cumulative sum at time $2n$,

In Feller's book, *An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*, in section 4 on page 75, the author goes on the prove that the probability of the first return to origin at time $2n$ is

$\begin{align}
P(s_1\ne 0, s_2 \ne 0, \ldots, s_{2n-1}\ne 0, s_{2n} \ne 0) &= 1 - f_{2} - f_{4} - \ldots- f_{2n}\\
&= 1 - (1 - u_{2}) - (u_{2} - u_{4}) - (u_{4} - u_{6}) - \ldots - (u_{2n-2}-u_{2n})\\
&= u_{2n} 
\end{align}$

It is not clear to me, how he equates the probabilities of the events $f_{2}=1-u_2$, $f_{4}=u_{2}-u_{4}$, $\ldots$ etcetera.

It would be really helpful, if someone could elaborate this fine point.

Cheers!

Comment: Clearly $f_{2n}<u_{2n}$ for $n>1$. I believe there is a typo and your first equation should be $$P[\mbox{first return time > 2n}] = P[s_1\neq 0,s_2\neq 0, ..., s_{2n-1}\neq 0, s_{2n}\neq 0] = 1-f_2 - ...- f_{2n}$$

Comment: @Michael, I corrected the typo, thanks.

Comment: That seems to be lemma 1 on page 76 (PDF file page 94) here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=2ahUKEwiPmLbR3qjjAhVXnp4KHQBrAnEQFjAFegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ime.usp.br%2F~fmachado%2FMAE5709%2FFellerV1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw377Lvab2f9_RcCQQy9Er15